# Position of maximum element in list under optimisation

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, maximum

For a list of several functions:

```
functions = {a[x,y,z],b[x,y,z],c[x,y,z],d[x,y,z]};
```

I want to maximize the maximum value of a function of three variables. This is easily done:

```
max = Maximize[Max[functions], {x,y,z}].
```

This returns the maximum value and the corresponding values `x -> x0,y -> y0,z -> z0`. I want the element in the list `functions` that corresponds to the maximum value. However, I want to determine this **inside** the Maximize step. Hence I am **not** looking for the following answer:

```
max = Maximize[Max[functions], {x,y,z}];
maxelement = Position[functions /. max[[2]], max[[1]]]
```

since this determines the max element separately. Instead I want to define `maxelement` inside the `Maximize` step in the definition for max.

**MWE**

```
a[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z] + 0.1 Sqrt[z]]^2);
b[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z] + 0.1 I Sqrt[z]]^2);
c[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z] + Sqrt[z]]^2);
d[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z]]);

functions = {a[x,y,z],b[x,y,z],c[x,y,z],d[x,y,z]};
maxvalue = Maximize[maxelement Max[functions], {x,y,z}];
```

where `max` inside the `Maximize` denotes the element of `functions` corresponding to the max value after substituting the values for `x,y,z` returned by `maxvalue` into functions.

Comment: Could you please provide a workable numerical example ?

Comment: @Lotus, done - see updated question.

Comment: What's the point of doing it this way? Can you explain what you need the index `maxelement` for inside `Maximize`? (I'm asking since this might affect potential answers)

Comment: @LukasLang, simply since `maxelement` may change according to the output of the maximisation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you can make a parameter representing the index of each function, e.g. if your initial equations are:

```
a[x_, y_, z_] := x - x^2 - y^2 - z^2;(*Maximum of 1/4*)
b[x_, y_, z_] := 2 y - x^2 - y^2 - z^2;(*Maximum of 1*)
c[x_, y_, z_] := 3 z - x^2 - y^2 - z^2;(*Maximum of 9/4*)
d[x_, y_, z_] := 4 x + y - x^2 - y^2 - z^2;(*Maximum of 17/4*)
```

they would become:

```
a[x_, y_, z_, p_] := (x - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)*KroneckerDelta[p, 1];
b[x_, y_, z_, p_] := (2 y - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)*KroneckerDelta[p, 2];
c[x_, y_, z_, p_] := (3 z - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)*KroneckerDelta[p, 3];
d[x_, y_, z_, p_] := (4 x + y - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)*KroneckerDelta[p, 4];
```

with the full list and fitting process as:

```
functions = {a[x, y, z, p], b[x, y, z, p], c[x, y, z, p], d[x, y, z, p]};
max = Maximize[Max[functions], {x, y, z, p}]

out: {17/4,{x->2,y->1/2,z->0,p->4}}
```

Where p->4 indicates that the last function (d) is the maximal one.